# Show that $((f_n))$ uniformky converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x))$ uniformly converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convergence-divergence

I need to show that the serie of functions: 
$$
((f_n)) 
$$

uniformly converges at the interval $[a,b]$ if and only if the serie: 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(f_n(x) - f_{n+1}(x))
$$

Uniformly converges at the interval $[a,b]$

In the solution for that question they say: 
$$
S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(f_k(x) - f_{k+1}(x)) = f_1(x) - f_{n+1}(x)
$$

Therefore the serie uniformly converges iff the serie 
$$
(f_1(x) - f_{n+1}(x)) 
$$

uniformly converges.

But: 
$$
\forall f: |(f_1(x) - f_n(x)) - (f_1(x) - f(x))| = |f_n(x) - f(x)|
$$

Therefore:
$$
(f_1(x) - f_n(x))
$$

Uniformly converges iff $(f_n(x))$ uniformly converges.

I didnt understand how they did: 
$$
\forall f: |(f_1(x) - f_n(x)) - (f_1(x) - f(x))| = |f_n(x) - f(x)|
$$

It seems like they try to show converges to the function: 
$$
f_1(x) - f(x)
$$

But shouldnt it be with $f(x)$ and not $f_1(x) - f(x)$ how did they bring that $f_1(x) - f(x)$?

I dont understand...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your $f_{1}(x)$ is a common function and adding a common part does not affect the convergence. $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(f_{n}(x)+c(x))=c(x)+\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)$$